# Swipe Cell to change a value inside the current cell from Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a cell in a tableView and I want to swipe it to change the value inside it repeatedly everytime I swipe. I have a Core Data that is used to store the data from another ViewController.

```
class HomeViewController: UITableViewController {

//MARK:- Properties

let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

// All Pills array
var pillsArray: [Pill] = []

var pillsRemaining: Int = 0


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    //reload table rows
    tableView.reloadData()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Set the interface color of User
    overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light

    // Find user directory path for Core Data
    let dataFilePath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)

    print(dataFilePath)

    // Load pillsArray
    loadPills()

    // Add title to Nav Controller
    let titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 30))
    //titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
    titleLabel.text = "Add Pills"
    titleLabel.textAlignment = .center
    titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Baskerville-Bold", size: 30)
    navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel

    // Register Cell
    self.registerCell()


}

//MARK:- TableView Datasource Methods

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // Add Label if the table View is Empty
    if pillsArray.count == 0 {
        let homeLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width, height: view.bounds.height))
        homeLabel.text = "Tap '+' to add Pill"
        homeLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        tableView.backgroundView = homeLabel
        tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCell.SeparatorStyle.none
        return 0
    } else {
        tableView.backgroundView = nil
        return pillsArray.count
    }


}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // Create Cell
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ReminderCell", for: indexPath) as? PillTableViewCell else {
        fatalError("Could not register cell with identifier ReminderCell")
    }

    let singlePill = pillsArray[indexPath.row]

    cell.pillNameCell.text = singlePill.pillName
    cell.instructionsCell.text = singlePill.pillInstruction
    cell.pillTimerCell.text = singlePill.pillStartTimer

    if let pillCountLabelText = singlePill.pillsCount {
        if let selectedPillTypeText = singlePill.selectedPillType {

            singlePill.pillsRemaining = pillCountLabelText

            cell.pillsLeft.text = pillCountLabelText

// if Int(pillCountLabelText) == pillsRemaining {
//                    cell.pillsLeft.text = "pills left \(pillCountLabelText) \.       (selectedPillTypeText)"
        //                } else {
    //                    cell.pillsLeft.text = "pills left \(pillsRemaining) \(selectedPillTypeText)"
     //                }


        }
    }

            //        cell.pillImageView.backgroundColor = singlePill.pillColor

    // Add color to pill taken img (ternary operation)

    cell.doneImageView.backgroundColor = singlePill.pillTaken ? .green : .red

    return cell
}

//MARK:- TableView Delegate Methods

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    // Delete pill from context and tableView
    //        context.delete(pillsArray[indexPath.row])
    //        pillsArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)

    // Toggle pill taken when selected
   //        pillsArray[indexPath.row].pillTaken = !pillsArray[indexPath.row].pillTaken

    savePillsTaken()

    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

}


// Left Swipe Actions (Take and Edit)
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

    // Write action code for Take a Pill
    let pillTakenAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Done") { (UIContextualAction, UIView, boolValue) in

       // Toggle pill taken when selected

        self.pillsArray[indexPath.row].pillTaken = !self.pillsArray[indexPath.row].pillTaken

         if let pillCountInt =  Int(self.pillsArray[indexPath.row].pillsCount ?? "0") {
            if let selectedDosageInt = Int(self.pillsArray[indexPath.row].selectedDosage ??  "0") {
                self.pillsRemaining = pillCountInt - selectedDosageInt
                self.pillsArray[indexPath.row].pillsRemaining = String(self.pillsRemaining)


                print(pillCountInt)
                print(selectedDosageInt)
            }
        }

        self.savePillsTaken()

        boolValue(true)

        print(self.pillsRemaining)
    }

    pillTakenAction.backgroundColor = .green

    let editPillAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Edit") { (UIContextualAction, UIView, boolValue) in
        print("Edit pill")
        boolValue(true)
    }
    editPillAction.backgroundColor = .gray

    let actionSwipes = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [pillTakenAction, editPillAction])

    return actionSwipes

}

// Right Swipe Action
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

    // Write action code for deleting a Pill
    let trashAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Delete") { (UIContextualAction, UIView, boolValue) in

        // Delete Pill from context and tableView

        self.context.delete(self.pillsArray[indexPath.row])
        self.pillsArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)

        self.savePillsTaken()

        boolValue(true)
    }

    trashAction.backgroundColor = .red

    let actionSwipes = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [trashAction])

    return actionSwipes

}


//MARK:- PillCell own methods

func registerCell() {
    let pillCell = UINib(nibName: "PillTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    self.tableView.register(pillCell, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ReminderCell")
}

//MARK:- Actions and Segue Methods

@IBAction func saveButtonPressed(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {


}


func savePillsTaken() {
    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch {

        print("Error saving pillsTaken in context, \(error)")
    }

    tableView.reloadData()

}

func loadPills() {
    let request : NSFetchRequest<Pill> = Pill.fetchRequest()
    do {
        pillsArray = try context.fetch(request)
    } catch {
        print("Error fetching data from context \(error)")
    }
}


 }
```

I want to Swipe right to change the pills count every time the person takes the pill dosage and it should show the right pill count.

Comment: What kind of problem are you seeing? The numbers are not getting updated in the tableView and/or coredata? Swipe right seems to delete rather than update so I'm assuming you are referring to the pillTakenAction on left swipe?

Comment: The cell has a label for pill count. Its not updating. I think my logic i right but i have no idea why its not changing

Comment: Does it update in Core Data?

Comment: Yes it updates in core data, i used print to check the output. The pill count goes down once its swipes and dont go down any more after u keep swiping nor the cell label text gets updated.

Comment: Nowhere in your code you are updating the pill count.